# JPA/Hibernate with Oracle Label Security

Tags: oracle, security, hibernate, spring, jpa

I have an application built with Spring and JPA/Hibernate that is working very well, but I now have a requirement to add Oracle Label Security. This will require the creation of a proxy user assigned with certain roles in addition to the actual user. I am unclear what goes into persistence.xml and what goes in code. Also, if we want to get really fancy, I would love to know how Spring can inject the proper persistence context with the mapping of user to proxy user.

If anyone has experience with this, any insight is appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Does "Oracle Label Security" mean VPD?

Comment: This may not be supported by hibernate. Not certian that this will help but check out this post http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg03843.html

Comment: Oracle Label Security is a chargeable extra to the Enterprise License which extends and wraps its Row Level Security VPD solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it the following way:

First get the basics of proxy authentication straight. This article looks promising: https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/using_oracle_proxy_authenticat

Assuming you have Webapplication (or anything else with a single point of entry) create a Filter wich accepts the request, identifies the user, establishes the user in the database using proxy authentication and then forwards the request.

This way your application will only see proper connections with the correct user established. So your Hibernate configuration should not be affected by this.

One warning: You are probably using a connection pools. These pools might not hand you an Oracle implementation of JDBC, but a wrapper through which you have to gain access to the oracle specific features needed. Make sure your application still uses the wrapper other wise the connection pool will not notice any exceptions thrown by the connection, thereby not recognize broken connections and will hand them out over and over again.